# Detect a geolocation with googleapis and receive current weather for this location from openweathermap with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, api, geolocation

**Detect a geolocation with googleapis and receive current weather for this location from openweathermap with jQuery**

I'm trying to get a current location and get current weather for that location.

Here is my **jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    function getCity(position) {


          function getPosition() {
             if (navigator.geolocation) {
                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(getCity);
             } else {
                 alert("Geolocation is not supported by this browser.");
               }
            }

            var url =  "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json? latlng=" +   position.coords.latitude + "," + position.coords.longitude;

            var city,
            country;
            $.getJSON(url, function(response) {
               city =  response.results[0].address_components[2].short_name;
               country = response.results[0].address_components[5].short_name;
               $('.yourLocationGoesHere').attr('value', city + ", " + country);
                });

                // Get weather by your location
                var celsius, fahrenheit, iconCode, iconUrl; 


             $.getJSON("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" + city +  "&APPID=7f5806c8f3fd28b03e2d6580a50732d6", function (data) {

               celsius = Math.round(data.main.temp - 273.15);
               fahrenheit = Math.round(9/5 * (data.main.temp - 273) + 32);
               iconCode = data.weather[0].icon;
               iconUrl = "http://openweathermap.org/img/w/" + iconCode + ".png";
               $(".icon").html("<img src='" + iconUrl + "'>");

               $(':radio').change(function(){ 
                 // "this" will be the checked radio element       
                 if (this.id === 'celsius'){
                    $(".showDegree").html(celsius + "&degC");
                 }else{ 
                    $(".showDegree").html(fahrenheit + "&degF");
                    }
                 });

               });
              }
            });
```

What am I doing wrong. Please help.

Comment: `iconUrl ` is only scoped inside the `$.getJSON()` callback and can't be accessed outside that callback. Look at error thrown *"iconUrl  is undefined"*

Comment: $.getJSON("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" + city + "&APPID=7f5806c8f3fd28b03e2d6580a50732d6", function (data) {

  var celsius = Math.round(data.main.temp - 273.15);
  var fahrenheit = Math.round(9/5 * (data.main.temp - 273) + 32);
  var iconCode = data.weather[0].icon;
  var iconUrl = "http://openweathermap.org/img/w/" + iconCode + ".png";
$(".icon").html("<img src='" + iconUrl + "'>");
});

Comment: @charlietfl can you please advise further?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here u go:

```
$(document).ready(function(){



      //Check geolocation success 
      if (navigator.geolocation) {
        console.log('Geolocation API success') 

        // Geolocation API not supported by current browser
        }  else {
           console.log('Geolocation API is not supported by your browser')
           };
        });

        // Get latitude and longitude
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position){
        var lat = position.coords.latitude;
        var long = position.coords.longitude;
        console.log("Your latitude is: " + lat + " and your longitude is: " + long);

        // Get formatted address using reverse geocoding for latitude/longitude 
        $.getJSON('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=' + lat + ',' + long +  '&key=AIzaSyCJw0QfJXXleECtFD5031OMG75lZMiC6dY',                 function(response){
         $('.yourLocationGoesHere').text(response.results[7].formatted_address);
           })

           $.getJSON('',)
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to be always aware of variables availability. If you define them inside a (callback) function, you will not be able to access them outside of it (I mean `celsius fahrenheit iconCode` and `iconUrl`).

So you can either define them before the function, just like you did with `city` and `country`, or place the code which uses them inside the same function.

Also keep in mind, that if you choose the first solution, the callback function is executed after the server responses, which takes some little time, so the variables won't be available right away anyway. So in this case you should process the incoming data within the callback function.

Comment: Much appreciated. Can you please have a look on what am doing wrong? http://codepen.io/ekilja01/pen/rjMQEG

Answer (score 0):

Lets try it, I hope that is a better solution to get current weather via using geolacation and Openweather API. Simply pass your OpenWeather API Key, you will get a JSON array, fetch your location and current weather. And you also use your weather icon which you want.

```
let loc = document.getElementById("location");
let tempIcon = document.getElementById("temp-icon")
let tempValue = document.getElementById("temp-value");
let tempUnit = document.getElementById("temp-unit");
let climate = document.getElementById("climate");
let iconFile; 
window.addEventListener("load", () => {
  let long;
  let lat;

  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
      long = position.coords.longitude;
      lat = position.coords.latitude;
      const proxy = "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/";
      const api = `${proxy}http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=${lat}&lon=${long}&appid=Your OpenWeather API KEy`;
      fetch(api)
        .then((response) => {
          return response.json();
        })
        .then((data) => {
          console.log(data);
          const { name } = data;
          const { feels_like, temp, temp_max, temp_min } = data.main;
          const { id, icon, main } = data.weather[0];
          tempValue.textContent = Math.round(feels_like - 273);
          loc.textContent = name;
          climate.textContent = main;
          if (id<250){
            tempIcon.src = './icons/storm.svg' ;
          }
          else if (id<350){
            tempIcon.src = './icons/drizzle.svg' ;
          }
          else if (id<550){
            tempIcon.src = './icons/rain.svg' ;
          }
          else if (id<650){
            tempIcon.src = './icons/snow.svg' ;
          }
          else if (id<800){
            tempIcon.src = './icons/atmosphere.svg' ;
          }
          else if (id===800){
            tempIcon.src = './icons/sun.svg' ;
          }
          else if(id>800){
            tempIcon.src = './icons/clouds.svg' ;
          }
          console.log(
            Math.round(temp - 273),
            Math.round(temp_max - 273),
            Math.round(temp_min - 273)
          );
          console.log(name);
        });
    });
  }
});
```